# Matrix grouping based on relation

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I got into problem to solve matrix grouping problem based on its relation.

**Problem**

Consider a group of people giving books to each other. More formally, group is composed of all the people who know one another, whether directly to transitively.

**Example**

Consider a matrix of input ***M***

Input

```
1100
1110
0110
0001
```

Output:

```
2
```

[image]

- There are n = 4 people numbered related[0] through related[3].
- There are 2 pairs who directly know each other: (related[0],
  related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)]) and (related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)], related[2]). Because a relation is
  transitive, the set of people {related[0], related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)], related[2]} is
  considered a single group.
- The remaining person, related[3], does not know any other people and
  is a separate group: {related[3]}
- There are a total of 2 groups.

**Example**

Input:

```
10000
01000
00100
00010
00001
```

Output:

```
5
```

No direct relationship are shown so there are 5 groups: {related
[0], related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)], related[2], related[3], related[4]}

**Example**

Input

```
1100000
1110000
0110000
0001000
0000110
0000110
0000001
```

Output

```
4
```

- There are 2 pairs who directly know each other: (related[0],
  related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)]) and (related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)], related[2]). Because a relation is
  transitive, the set of people {related[0], related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)], related[2]} is
  considered a single group.
- There is 1 pair who directly know each other: (related[4], related[5]). So they are considered as single group {related[4], related[5]}
- The remaining person, related[3], related[6] does not know any other people and
  is a separate group: {related[3]}, {related[6]}
- There are total 4 group : {{related[0], related[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC3Rp.png)], related[2]}, {related[4], related[5]}, {related[3]}, {related[6]} }

---

I need help with how to approach with this kind of problems.

**Code**
(I tried not completed)

```
def countGroup(matrix):
    people = set()
    group1 = set()
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        people.add(i) 
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if i == j:
              # next
              continue
            if matrix[i][j]:
                group1.add((i,j))
                people.discard(i)
                people.discard(j)
                # group1.add(i)
                # group1.add(j)
    print(people, "people")
    print(group1, "group1")
    count = len(people)
    if group1:
        count += 1

    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there, the issue is the if isn't quite right, and you need to make more use of sets. Haven't tested the code but should work with perhaps a few minor tweaks, my python is a bit rusty.

```
def countGroup(matrix):
    people = set()
    group1 = set()
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        people.add(i) # Quick way to build a list of all the people
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if i == j: # Not useful, you should know yourself. 
              # Could avoid this by using itertools.combinations
              continue
            if matrix[i][j] == 1: # we just want to know
                group1.add(i)
                group1.add(j)
    group2 = people - group1 # Anyone not in group1 is in group2.

    return (group1, group2)
```

Comment: This works for 2 group relation but what if I have a big matrix for 10 people as input and there are many grouping relation. Consider `matrix = [
 [1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
]` it has group 4, related {[0,1,2], [4,5], [3], [6]}. How can it get this your algorithm please help

Comment: Please update your question with that information and explain what you are really looking for in terms of group. You may want to look into adjacency lists as a way to store graphs instead. I was going to give an example of building an adjacency list then having everyone in the adjacency list being part of group 1 while everyone not in being part of group 2. But it was excessively complicated for this purpose and the above algorithm works better. Here is a graph utility I usually use for building them (but it's ruby not python) https://gist.github.com/MyklClason/fe603a6005a1dedc6ec65fda7ff47f68

Comment: Yup just use adjacency lists. That will let you know that this person knows these people. From there you can use a breadth first search to get the list of all people that each other knows. What you are looking for is known as `Connected Components`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this pseudo code:

```
relationship_groups = []
for i, relationship in enumerate(relationships):
  for j, related in enumerate(relationship):
    if related == 1:
       # for all sets in relationship_groups
           # check if i or j exists in those sets
           # if j, break, if i add j
       # if you don't find any relationship
           # create a new group (set) for i and j and add them
           # to relationship groups
# return the length of relationship groups.
```

That should get you most of the way there.